# C++ Library Creation using namespace

Tags: c++

I am trying to explore namespace and trying to create a sample library the way I do in C. I have never done this in C++ , so here is what I am doing. This is my code which works fine and which I want to put in separate Files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace TCS{
    class employee{
        int uID;
        std::string name;

        public:
        employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name)
        {
            this->uID=uId;
            (this->name).assign(name);
            }
        int getID()
        {
            return uID;
            }
        std::string getName()
                {
                    return name;
            }
        };
    }

using namespace std;

class employee{
        int uID;
        string name;

        public:
        employee(const int& uId, const string& name)
        {
            this->uID=uId;
            (this->name).assign(name);
            }
        int getID()
        {
            return uID;
            }
        string getName()
                {
                    return name;
            }
        };


int main()
{

    employee TechMEmp1(1,"Andrew");

    TCS::employee TCSEmp1(1,"Thomas");

    cout << "Tech M Employee is :- ID : " << TechMEmp1.getID() << " Name  : "
    << TechMEmp1.getName() << endl;

    cout << "TCS Employee is :- ID : " << TCSEmp1.getID() << " Name  : "
    << TCSEmp1.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Now I am just trying to replicate the way I put contents in separate files in C. I cteated a file TCS.h with content :

```
#ifndef TCS_HEADER
#define TCS_HEADER
namespace TCS{
    class employee{
        int uID;
        std::string name;
        public:
        employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name);
        int getID();
        std::string getName();
        };
    }
#endif
```

Another File : TCSNamespace.cpp with content

```
#include "TCS.h"
#include <string>

TCS::employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name);
        {
            this->uID=uId;
            (this->name).assign(name);
            }
int TCS::getID();
        {
            return uID;
            }
std::string TCS::getName();
        {
            return name;
            }
```

And my final file which contains main is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TCS.h"


using namespace std;

class employee{
        int uID;
        string name;

        public:
        employee(const int& uId, const string& name)
        {
            this->uID=uId;
            (this->name).assign(name);
            }
        int getID()
        {
            return uID;
            }
        string getName()
                {
                    return name;
            }
        };


int main()
{

    employee TechMEmp1(1,"Andrew Thomas");

    TCS::employee TCSEmp1(1,"Thomas Hula");

    cout << "Tech M Employee is :- ID : " << TechMEmp1.getID() << " Name  : "
    << TechMEmp1.getName() << endl;

    cout << "TCS Employee is :- ID : " << TCSEmp1.getID() << " Name  : "
    << TCSEmp1.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

I am using Cygwin and try to compile the files separately, when I enter the command:
g++ -Wall -c TCSNamespace.cpp ( I think this will compile my TCSNamespace.cpp the way it compiles c files)
I get:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c TCSNamespace.cpp
In file included from TCSNamespace.cpp:1:
TCS.h:6: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
TCS.h:6: error: expected `;' before "name"
TCS.h:8: error: expected unqualified-id before '&' token
TCS.h:8: error: expected `,' or `...' before '&' token
TCS.h:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `parameter' with no type
TCS.h:10: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
TCS.h:10: error: expected `;' before "getName"
TCSNamespace.cpp:4: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
TCSNamespace.cpp:5: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
TCSNamespace.cpp:5: error: expected `,' or `;' before '{' token
TCSNamespace.cpp:9: error: `int TCS::getID()' should have been declared inside `TCS'
TCSNamespace.cpp:10: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
TCSNamespace.cpp:10: error: expected `,' or `;' before '{' token
TCSNamespace.cpp:13: error: `std::string TCS::getName()' should have been declared inside `TCS'
TCSNamespace.cpp:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
TCSNamespace.cpp:14: error: expected `,' or `;' before '{' token
```

What I intend to do is to separately compile TCSNamespace.cpp nd Namespace.cpp and then link them to obtain executable with below commands:

```
g++ -Wall -c TCSNamespace.cpp
g++ -Wall -c Namespace.cpp
gcc  TCSNamespace.o Namespace.o –o Namespace
```

Could anyone please tell where am I going wrong ? I also want to know that creating "TCS.h" in C++ the way it is done in C , is it good practice because C++ uses  type of header.

Thanks

Comment: You still need to declare dependencies for your classes in their respective header files. Do NOT rely on the including source (.cpp) file to include them for you. Example: Where does `TCS.h` get the definition of `std::string` from? This is one reason it is usually good practice to include your headers *before* the system headers in your .cpp files, thereby ensuring things will not compile unless dependencies are fulfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCS.h` needs to `#include <string>`.

Currently, `TCS.h`  is included before `<string>` so the declaration of `std::string` is not known at the point where `name` is processed.

```
#ifndef TCS_HEADER
#define TCS_HEADER
#include <string>
namespace TCS{
    class employee{
        int uID;
        std::string name;
        public:
        employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name);
        int getID();
        std::string getName();
        };
    }
#endif
```

Also, @ForEverR beat me to it on the `.cpp` contents, so I'll just note you can write:

```
TCS::employee::employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name);
{
    this->uID=uId;
    (this->name).assign(name);
}
```

Finally:

> I also want to know that creating "TCS.h" in C++ the way it is done in
>   C , is it good practice because C++ uses type of header.

Answer: Yes.

Answer (score 3):

One problem I see is that you are not declaring your functions in the .cpp file to a member of class employee. You need to wrap your whole .cpp file with the namespace and then have each member function be preceded by the class name. You can also precede each function with the namespace `TCS::employee::employee(...)` rather than wrapping the whole code with a namespace as I did below, but that can become very cumbersome to constantly write that all out. Also be careful with your semicolons in the function definitions.

```
#include "TCS.h"
#include <string>

namespace TCS {
    employee::employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name) // <-- remove semicolon
    {
        this->uID=uId;
        (this->name).assign(name);
    }
    int employee::getID() // <-- remove semicolon
    {
        return uID;
    }
    std::string employee::getName() // <-- remove semicolon
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Also you need to remove the semicolons from the end of the function definitions as shown above.

I would also suggest including `string` in TCS.h because it is necessary for any files that include TCS.h to have the string include.

Answer (score 2):

TCS.h needs to include `<string>` header

TCSNamespace.cpp should be

```
#include "TCS.h"
#include <string>

namespace TCS {

employee::employee(const int& uId, const std::string& name)
        {
            this->uID=uId;
            (this->name).assign(name);
        }
int employee::getID()
        {
            return uID;
        }
std::string employee::getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
}
```

In your case - you don't specify, that functions are members of class.